# POCO: How to properly attach StreamSocket to SecureStreamSocket?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, poco-libraries

I try to attach connected StreamSocket to SecureStreamSocket:

```
class MyConnection : public TCPServerConnection {
  private:
    Context::Ptr m_pContext;
  public:
    MyConnection(const StreamSocket& socket, Context::Ptr pContext)
    : TCPServerConnection(socket),
      m_pContext(pContext)
    {
    }

    virtual void run() {
      SecureStreamSocket secureSock(SecureStreamSocket::attach(socket(), m_pContext));
      socket() = secureSock;
    }
}
```

But I have SSLException:

```
SSL Exception [N4Poco3Net12SSLExceptionE]: error:140C5042:SSL routines:SSL_UNDEFINED_FUNCTION:called a function you should not call
```

Initialization of SSL library was performed:

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL(); // inside Application::initialize
```

The context init after SSL initialization:

```
 Poco::Net::Context::Ptr pContext =
      new Poco::Net::Context(
          Poco::Net::Context::SERVER_USE,
          "server.key",
          "server.crt",
          "/path/to/certs/"
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite SecureStreamSocket::attach(...) this way:

```
SecureStreamSocket SecureStreamSocket::attach(const StreamSocket& streamSocket, Context::Ptr pContext)
{
  SecureStreamSocketImpl* pImpl = new SecureStreamSocketImpl(static_cast<StreamSocketImpl*>streamSocket.impl()), pContext);
  SecureStreamSocket result(pImpl);
  if (pImpl->context()->isForServerUse())
      pImpl->acceptSSL();
  else
      pImpl->connectSSL();
  return result;
}
```

Thanks for [this post](http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5269&p=8563&hilit=ssl%20SecureStreamSocket#p8563). Now it works well for servers and clients.